# Foundation 5: enable button radii (radiuses) globally

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

the `buttons` component has this mixin, `@mixin button-style($bg:$primary-color, $radius:false, $disabled:false)` being referenced this way:

```
@include exports("button") {
  @if $include-html-button-classes {

    // Default styles applied outside of media query
    button, .button {
      @include button-base;
      @include button-size;
      @include button-style;
[...]
```

so, elements being  or .button never will have $radius true because the mixin is invoked without any arguments, hence the default `false` being set.
Is there a smart way I don't know, maybe in SASS, to enable that globally though?

Answer (score 1):

**Add this to your `app.scss`:**

```
button, .button {
    @include button($radius:true);
}
```

It will modify the button input and class using `_button.scss`'s mixin.

Comment: They don't have a global variable that sets this. You can submit a patch, patch your own version, add the radius class to all of your buttons, or have duplicate code. An in between would be setting `$include-html-button-classes` to `false` and adding the modified button constructor to your `app.scss` file. An upgrade wouldn't get any fixes/features to the constructor, but would for the rest of the `_buttons.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

In SASS, you can overwrite a default argument. So to enable border-radius for buttons, you should do this:

```
@include exports("button") {
  @if $include-html-button-classes {

    // Default styles applied outside of media query
    button, .button {
      @include button-base;
      @include button-size;
      @include button-style($radius: true);
[...]
```

Default border-radius for buttons is set to 3px

```
//_buttons.scss

[...]
// We can control how much button radius us used.
@if $radius == true { @include radius($button-radius); }  //$button-radius = $global-radius = 3px
@else if $radius { @include radius($radius); }
}
[...]
```

If you want to change this border-radius, Foundation recommendeds to unocomment these lines in `_settings.scss` file and change 3px by the desired value:

```
// Line 61
// $global-radius: 3px;

// Line 236
// $button-radius: $global-radius;
```

Or if you want to set a value (e.g. 5px) for $button-radius that differs from $global-radius all you have to do is change in `_settings.scss` this:

```
// Line 236
// $button-radius: 5px
```

**Another way to set border-radius for buttons is**

```
@include exports("button") {
  @if $include-html-button-classes {

    // Default styles applied outside of media query
    button, .button {
      @include button-base;
      @include button-size;
      @include button-style($radius: 5px); // Replace 5px by the size that you want
[...]
```

I personally recommend the first method to mantain an organized structure

Comment: sorry Alex, just stumbled upon this again and realized I didn't realize you answered.

Thing is: regarding your first method, I don't want to overwrite that mixing invocation since it's Framework country and I must not change anything here.

Regarding SASS, anything is clear to me, but I have no idea how this is intended from Zurb Foundation's side...